# Run Raspberry Pi Zero W image in qemu

Tags: yocto, qemu, raspberry-pi-zero

I had generated a `core-image-minimal` using `yocto` for `Raspberry Pi zero W`.
I'm trying to run it using `qemu-system-arm` using this command:

```sh
sudo qemu-system-arm -kernel uImage-1-4.19.93+git0+3fdcc814c5-r0-raspberrypi0-wifi-20200208095028.bin \
-cpu arm1176 \
-m 512 \
-M raspi2 \
-no-reboot \
-serial stdio \
-append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash" \
-drive "file=core-image-minimal-raspberrypi0-wifi-20200208095028.rootfs.tar.bz2,index=0,media=disk,format=raw"
```

but the emulator run as a blank screen.

my changes inside `local.conf`:

```
MACHINE ??= "raspberrypi0-wifi"
RPI_USE_U_BOOT = "1"
ENABLE_UART = "1"
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "tar.bz2 ext4.xz"
SDIMG_ROOTFS_TYPE = "ext4.xz"
DISTRO_FEATURES_remove = "x11"
```

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi 2 has a different processor BCM2836 (quad core) and different memory map that RPiZero or RPi1
What I did was to modify and recompile QEMU to support Raspberry Pi Zero W.
You can find my patched fork at:
https://github.com/igwtech/qemu